# Why will this code not print anything to the console?

Tags: printing

I am very new to java as I have only started yesterday and I am trying to make a little game where a random number is generated and you have to try to guess that number. The problem I am having right now is nothing will come out of the console. I am not sure what is causing this as it might be  the code or the interpreter I am using. Here is the code for you guys to check over. Let me know what I did wrong and if you can find a fix, thanks.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Random 

{
    int Ran = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int Num = input.nextInt();
    public static void main(String[] args){}
    {System.out.println("Geuss a number and see if it is correct!");
    }
    {
        if (Num == Ran)
        {System.out.println("Correct! The number was " + Ran);
        }
        else{
            System.out.println("You are wrong!");
        }
        }
    public void If(boolean b) {}
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

you have empty{}

```
 public static void main(String[] args){
System.out.println("Geuss a number and see if it is correct!");
   }
```

Also do not write IF as a function. If is native expression in native coding.
There is already if clause so try to give unique names.

```
  import java.util.Scanner;
  public class Random 

 {
int Ran = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
int Num = input.nextInt();
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  System.out.println("Geuss a number and see if it is correct!");
   if (Num == Ran)
    {System.out.println("Correct! The number was " + Ran);
    }
    else{
        System.out.println("You are wrong!");
    }
}
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

try this.

```
    import java.util.Scanner;
    public class Random 
    {
        int Ran = (int) Math.floor(Math.random() * 9);
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int Num = input.nextInt();
        public static void main(String[] args){
           System.out.println("Geuss a number and see if it is correct!");
            if (Num == Ran)
            {System.out.println("Correct! The number was " + Ran);
            }
            else{
                System.out.println("You are wrong!");
            }
        }
        public void If(boolean b) {}
        }
    }
```